# My tailwind does not apply to my react typescript project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, craco

I followed the tutorial on the tailwind website, and I can't apply tailwind to my project.
I really don't understand....
Here are my files :)
[image]

App.css

```
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

app.tsx

```
import { Pokemon } from "./Pokemon";
export default function App() {
  return <Pokemon />;
}
```

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>

);
```

my craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    style: {
      postcss: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
     "build": "craco build",
     "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

tailwind config file:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

I hope to have some help, because I followed the tutorial...
I tried to put some code in the pokedex file where I imported app.css
but no tailwind style is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines you added in App.css. You just need them in index.css file.

Do theses updates :

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

Create this file in the root postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/